# Grouping a list with specified fields and then have all fields back in list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a list (mylist) with 5 fields x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
I want to to group by mylist by x1 and x2 ,and then have a new list resultList with all 5 fields x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 which are grouped by x1 and x2.
I want to do it with Linq

```
    var result = mylist.GroupBy(row => new { row.x1, row.x2})
```

This gives a list with two fields row.x1, row.x2. how can i get the rest fields

**Edit:** Suppose this is mylist:
      x1    x2     x3     x4     x5

---

```
 1     '=C'    'a'    'b'    'c'
 2     '+A'    'd'    'e'    'f'     
 1     '=C'    'g'    'h'    'i'
 4     '=C'    'j'    'k'    'l'
```

I want to have this result:

```
 x1    x2     x3     x4     x5
```

---

```
 1     '=C'    'a'    'b'    'c'    
 1     '=C'    'g'    'h'    'i'
 4     '=C'    'j'    'k'    'l'
 2     '+A'    'd'    'e'    'f'
```

Answer (score 0):

After Grouping which x3,x4,x5 value do you want to get like which have minimum value or maximum value etc.

x1 | x2 | x3 |
  A  | B|1
  A  | B|2

when you group on X1 and X2 then it give only A , B but you have to tell which value of x3 column you want to get.

Comment: if you have ten rows after grouping if it give two rows only , then which value of  x3,x4,x5  do you want to fetch ? you have to tell that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var res = (from m in mylist
            group m by new {m.x1 , m.x2} into grouped
            select new { key = grouped.Key , values = grouped.ToList() }).ToList();
            foreach (var re in res)
            {
                var values = re.values;
                //get other fields from values
            }
```